# Int object is not callable in the code ${{order.get_cart_total}}

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have the following code in the model, while calling the get_cart_total int not callable or unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'method'appaers

I am expecting to get total from get_cart_total

```
class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=False)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)


    @property
    def get_cart_items(self):
        orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum([item.quantity for item in orderitems])
        return total

    @property
    def get_cart_total(self):
    
        items = self.get_cart_items()
        for item in items:
            total += item.get_total()
        return total

    


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    ORDER_ITEM_TYPE = (
        ('type1', 'Collection1'),
        ('type2', 'Collection2'),
    )
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    collection_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=ORDER_ITEM_TYPE)
    collection1 = models.ForeignKey(Collection1, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    collection2 = models.ForeignKey(Collection2, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

    def get_total(self):
        if self.collection_type == "type1":
            return self.collection1.price * self.quantity
        elif self.collection_type == "type2":
            return self.collection2.price * self.quantity
```

Comment: Pls format your `Order` and `OrderItem` model classes properly

Comment: Please, add full traceback you get

Answer (score 0):

Since `self.get_cart_items` is a property, you do not need to call it. You can either remove the `@property` decorator, or just expect `self.get_cart_items` to be an integer already, not a method.

```
    @property
    def get_cart_total(self):
    
-       items = self.get_cart_items()
+       items = self.get_cart_items
        for item in items:
            total += item.get_total()
        return total
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set `get_cart_items` as `property` which is treated as an attribute of an object, not as a method in that matter. You need to delete that decorator or `()` from your calculations.

Option 1:

```
@property
def get_cart_items(self):
    orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
    total = sum([item.quantity for item in orderitems])
    return total

@property
def get_cart_total(self):
    items = self.get_cart_items
    for item in items:
        total += item.get_total()
    return total
```

Option 2:

```
def get_cart_items(self):
    orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
    total = sum([item.quantity for item in orderitems])
    return total

@property
def get_cart_total(self):
    items = self.get_cart_items()
    for item in items:
        total += item.get_total()
    return total
```

Answer (score 0):

- Your `get_cart_items` is a property method, which is not callable, so remove `()` when you want to use this method
- `get_cart_items()` is returning an **int** value which is the sum of item quantities, so here on your code `items = self.get_cart_items()` you can't loop through an integer value

Fix your code accordingly

```py
    @property
    def get_cart_items(self):
        return self.orderitem_set.all()

    @property
    def get_cart_total(self):
        items = self.get_cart_items
        for item in items:
            total += item.get_total()
        return total
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of points:

1. 'get_cart_items' is a property (@property decorator) so you should treat it as a such. Change: `items = self.get_cart_items()` to `items = self.get_cart_items`, or remove the @property decorator.
2. 'get_cart_items' is not returning a list of OrderItem objects, but a sum of item quantity (an integer)
3. The 'total' variable is not initialized in 'get_cart_total' method.

Try something like this for 'get_cart_total' method:

```
def get_cart_total(self):
    total = 0
    for item in self.orderitem_set.all():
        total += item.get_total()
    return total
```